# Plot for NProbability

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, probability-or-statistics

How build some `Plot` for many `NProbability` results? I want draw a `Plot` for `NProbability` results, where I have a range for  **rad** variable from 0.2 to 0.9.

```
node = 15;    
rad = 0.8;
conf = 2;
SeedRandom[conf];
\[ScriptCapitalG] = SpatialGraphDistribution[node, rad];
RandomGraph[\[ScriptCapitalG]]
\[ScriptCapitalD] = 
  GraphPropertyDistribution[Boole[ConnectedGraphQ[g]], 
   g \[Distributed] \[ScriptCapitalG]];
NProbability[x == 1, x \[Distributed] \[ScriptCapitalD]]
```

[image]

```
Out[2] = 0.999857
```

Comment: I’m not seeing a question.

Comment: how build some `Plot` for many `NProbability` results? I try `Plot[NProbability[x == 1, 
  x \[Distributed] 
   GraphPropertyDistribution[Boole[ConnectedGraphQ[g]], 
    g \[Distributed] SpatialGraphDistribution[15, rad]]], {rad, 0.2, 
  0.9}]`. It's hevy code for my CPU and i still wait for result.

Comment: Please place the question in the text above (and not just in a comment).  What happened when you tried the command you give in your comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the use of `NProbability` simply takes a long time.  (`NExpectation` in this case is conceptually the same but takes even longer.)  One approach that seems to speed things up is to use `RandomVariate` to sample the distribution.

```
prob[node_, rad_] := Module[{\[ScriptCapitalG], \[ScriptCapitalD]},
  \[ScriptCapitalG] = SpatialGraphDistribution[15, rad];
  \[ScriptCapitalD] = 
   GraphPropertyDistribution[Boole[ConnectedGraphQ[g]], 
    g \[Distributed] \[ScriptCapitalG]];
  N[Mean[RandomVariate[\[ScriptCapitalD], 10000]]]]

data = Table[{rad, prob[15, rad]}, {rad, 0.2, 0.9, 0.02}];
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True]
```

[image: Probabilities for values of rad]

You could change the number of samples taken from 10,000 to 100,000 but that probably won't improve the precision of the result by very much while taking 10 times longer.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's what I meant. I am a beginner Mathematica user and I do not know many facilities.